# DCMTK: Write DICOM file to memory

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

I am using DCMTK to write DICOM files to disk and this works quite well. So, I briefly do something as follows:

```
DcmDataset * ds = image->dcm_file_format->getDataset();
// Modify DICOM as needed...
DcmFileFormat file_format(ds);
file_format.saveFile(filename);
```

This works quite well. However, I would like to write the contents to some memory buffer. So, I would like to do something as follows:

```
char * buffer = new char[file_length];
```

and then somehow use the file_format to write to this buffer instead of the file. I see there is a 'write' method in the DcmFileFormat but could not figure out how to use it where I could specify my own byte array for it to write to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a look at the source code of [Orthanc](http://www.orthanc-server.com/), a lightweight Vendor Neutral Archive for medical imaging. Orthanc writes its DICOM instances to memory buffers (`std::string`) in the method `Orthanc::FromDcmtkBridge::SaveToMemoryBuffer()`. Here is a [direct link to this method](https://code.google.com/p/orthanc/source/browse/OrthancServer/FromDcmtkBridge.cpp?name=Orthanc-0.8.6#669).

Comment: Sorry I needed a DCMTK option.

Comment: Just copy/past the code from Orthanc... it is licensed under the GPLv3+. Downvoting this answer is unfair.

Comment: Here is a new direct URL to the method, because of the retirement of Google Code: https://goo.gl/qTVA0E